# Set DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION in YAML file not working for MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-rest, objectmapper, json-view

I have set following in spring boot yaml file. But not working. 
I checked the question [Set DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION in YAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137920/set-default-view-inclusion-in-yaml-file). But there they have given answer for new custom objectmapper object, but not using the spring convertor object.

spring:
  jackson:
    mapper:
      DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION: true

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following config:

```
spring:
    jackson:
        default-property-inclusion: DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION
```

Comment: It will give following error in yaml file: Expecting a 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Include[ALWAYS, NON_NULL, NON_ABSENT, NON_EMPTY, ...]' but got 'DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION'

Comment: Both different properties and purpose