# Use JsonView to selectively hide fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jackson

I am trying to selectively hide certain fields in a response, depending on the role of the user requesting it. From what I have been able to understand, `JsonView` from `Jackson` may be the way to go.

I need to be able to display all fields, UNLESS they have been marked with a specific access level. I have created the following structure for the access levels:

(Quick note: I have left the base user in there, but it shouldn't really matter)

```java
public class View {
    public static final Map<Role, Class> MAPPING = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        MAPPING.put(Role.ROLE_ADMIN, Admin.class);
        MAPPING.put(Role.ROLE_USER, AuthenticatedUser.class);
    }

    public interface User {}
    public interface AuthenticatedUser extends User {}
    public interface Admin extends AuthenticatedUser {}
}
```

And used them as follows:

```java
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String baseInfo;

    @JsonView(View.AuthenticatedUser.class)
    private String userInfo;

    @JsonView(View.Admin.class)
    private String secretInfo;

    ...
}
```

(PS: I have stripped away all the non essential annotations, etc.)

Now, I expect that depending on the level of access, the responses are as follows:

1. Non-authenticated user:

   ```
   {
       "id": 1,
       "baseInfo": "Some basic info"
   }
   ```
2. Authenticated user:

   ```
   {
       "id": 1,
       "baseInfo": "Some basic info",
       "userInfo": "Info only the user should be able to see"
   }
   ```
3. Admin user:

   ```
   {
       "id": 1,
       "baseInfo": "Some basic info",
       "userInfo": "Info only the user should be able to see",
       "secretInfo": "Info only the admin can see"
   }
   ```

I used code from [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-role-filter-json) tutorial to integrate it into spring security and my own structure.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class SecurityJsonViewControllerAdvice extends AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice {

    @Override
    protected void beforeBodyWriteInternal(MappingJacksonValue bodyContainer, MediaType contentType, MethodParameter returnType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities() != null) {
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
            List<Role> foundRoles = authorities.stream()
                    .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                    .map(Role::get).collect(Collectors.toList());

            if (foundRoles.contains(null)) {
                System.err.println("User has no auth. Setting no serialization view");
                return;
            }

            List<Class> jsonViews = foundRoles.stream().map(View.MAPPING::get)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (jsonViews.size() == 1) {
                System.err.println("Setting " + jsonViews.get(0) + " as serialization view");
                bodyContainer.setSerializationView(jsonViews.get(0));
                return;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ambiguous @JsonView declaration for roles "
                    + authorities.stream()
                    .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
        }
        System.err.println("No auth found");
    }
}
```

(Pardon the awful code, I have been trying a bit of everything...)

At this point, I expect the result to be as the one that I stated above, but I keep on getting all fields, without any kind of filtering. No type of annotation avoids the fields from being serialized. I know I could set the default to be that all fields are excluded EXCEPT for the ones I annotate, but it would mean annotating all fields and the project is quite big.

Is my initial assumption about `JsonView` wrong, or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried your code but I get a different result. Instead of all fields I get none, only an empty json message `{}` as response (if the Role is `User`). Only those fields which are annotated with `@JsonView` get serialized if the role does match. Maybe you removed a essential annotation from your sample code?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just created another project and it works as you said meaning that no fields are returned. You need to set the `spring.jackson.mapper.default_view_inclusion=true` property to have all fields. With this project, I get the expected result back, so I guess the issue is somewhere else in my code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @second 's comment, I have been able to figure out the issue. As it turns out I made two small mistakes:

### 1. Setting Jackson to include all properties by default

The first change is setting `spring.jackson.mapper.default_view_inclusion` to `true` in your `application.properties` file. By doing so, Jackson will include all properties by default, removing the issue where the payload is empty

### 2. Using a "base" user

Whenever an unauthenticated user tries to access the system, we need to set the serialization view to a base user.  In my post above, I have the `User` View but I never used it. Setting this as a default serialization view (in the interceptor above) solves the issue and the result is the one I stated above.

### EDIT

I uploaded an example [here](https://github.com/pennal/JsonViewsDemo). It's very simple but it shows how the different fields can be excluded. Use like this:

- `http://localhost:8080/test`

  ```
  {
      "id":1,
      "baseInfo":"This is the base info"
  }
  ```
- `http://localhost:8080/test?view=user`

  ```
  {
      "id":1,
      "baseInfo":"This is the base info",
      "userInfo":"This is the user info"
  }
  ```
- `http://localhost:8080/test?view=admin`

  ```
  {
      "id":1,
      "baseInfo":"This is the base info",
      "userInfo": "This is the user info",
      "secretInfo":"This is the secret info"
  }
  ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried to verify this, but I am still missing something here. I tried to provide the config with the code from this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45138069) instead of using the properties file. I also added a line `bodyContainer.setSerializationView(View.User.class);` to the beginning of the interceptor, but I am still not getting the non annotated fields.

Comment: Hey, check out the example I added. I removed spring security but the basics are the same

Comment: Thanks for the github project upload. I'll confirmed that yours is working, but I have still not found the difference in my project. I would say it does not pick up the `default_view_inclusion`, but I have no idea why.